# How to read a file content from multiple compressed files without decompressing the folder?

Tags: shell

I have a number of log files compressed into a folder called logfiles.gz
This is a samlpe for creating and compressing the files:

```
touch log1.txt
touch log2.txt

echo "June 5, 2014. The system works!" >> log1.txt
echo "June 5, 2014. The system found a problem at line 3!" >> log2.txt

find . -name "log*.txt" |xargs tar -czvf logfiles.gz
gzip logfiles.gz
```

I want to view the content of one of them (log1.txt) without decompressing the whole folder or even that file.

I wanted to use zcat but do not know how to point to my desired file inside the folder! I tried:

```
zcat logfiles.gz/log1.txt
```

But got the following error:

> (logfiles.gz/log1.txt.Z): Not a directory

If I want to use zcat, how do I point to my file? Or there is any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using `tar` and `gzip`—which is a correct way of handling this—but you are not using the strengths of `tar` to achieve this goal.

The `tar` command stands for “tape archive” [as explained here](http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/tar.html):

> The purpose of the tar (Tape ARchive) command is to manage an archive
>   of files on tape or disk. Tar stores the structure of directories so
>   that archives of entire directories, complete with sub-directories and
>   files can be created, extracted or a table of contents produced. Tar
>   is used primarily as a backup and transfer tool. Single files or
>   entire directories along with the original structure, can be written
>   to a file or directly to a tape.

So with that in mind, here are my adjustments to your shell command list to make it clear this is a `tar` & `gzip` archive.

```
touch log1.txt
touch log2.txt

echo 'June 5, 2014. The system works!' >> log1.txt
echo 'June 5, 2014. The system found a problem at line 3!' >> log2.txt

find . -maxdepth 1 -name "log*.txt" | xargs tar -czvf logfiles.tar
gzip logfiles.tar
```

Note I also changed your double-quotes to single quotes for the `echo` lines so the exclamation marks (`!`) would be properly added to the files. And I added a `-maxdepth 1` so the command doesn’t act on every single `.txt` file in your directory. Also, I changed the archive name to `logfiles.tar` so it can properly be compressed to `logfiles.tar.gz`.

With that done, the final resulting file should be:

```
logfiles.tar.gz
```

Now just use `tar` to extract your specific file like this:

```
tar -xvf logfiles.tar.gz log1.txt
```

The `log1.txt` is the full path to the file in the `tar` archive. So if it were nested in a folder like `this/is/a/structure/` then you could extract that file by indicating `this/is/a/structure/log1.txt`.

There is no need to run `gzip -d` since modern versions of `tar` automatically know how to decompress the compressed data & go straight to the `tar` contents inside.

**EDIT:** Since the original poster wants to see the contents of a file without actually decompressing the archive this should work:

```
tar xfO logfiles.tar.gz log1.txt
tar xfO logfiles.tar.gz log2.txt
```

And the nice thing about this is you can pipe it to `less` or `more` like this:

```
tar xfO logfiles.tar.gz log1.txt | less
tar xfO logfiles.tar.gz log2.txt | less

tar xfO logfiles.tar.gz log1.txt | more
tar xfO logfiles.tar.gz log2.txt | more
```

The `x` and `f` options basically just tell `tar` to extract a file. Which is normal operation. But the magic in this is using the `O` option which will force the output to be written to standard out without actually extracting the file:

```
 -O      (x, t modes only) In extract (-x) mode, files will be written to
         standard out rather than being extracted to disk.  In list (-t)
         mode, the file listing will be written to stderr rather than the
         usual stdout.
```

Comment: Your answer tells me how to decompress one of the files in the compressed folder. I edited the question, because what I ment to know was how to read the content without decompressing the file. Also the reason I used tar was to group files together so that I can compress all of them at once. I will give you an up vote because your suggestion makes me one step closer to what I am looking for. (But sill waiting for a closer solution)